# Cannot logon to RDP Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, rdp, user-accounts, domaincontroller

I am not able to logon into RDP of windows server 2012 R2.
I have setup a local user with administrator group and remote desktop users group.
But the problem is that the computers belong to a domain and I only have administrator cmd non-interactive access.
I want to logon to that system of mine without logging on to the domain.
I only want to login to the "System" without logging on to the domain.
Any cmd commands will do the trick.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think your question is better suited for http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: thanks for the tip!